# making HTML id a variable in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

i am trying to make an image named id='pr' a variable like this.
my HTML code is

```
<div id="main">
<img id ='pr' style="width: 500px;height: 600px;"src="https://i.redd.it/2u0y0z5i12py.png">
</div>
```

My javascript code:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var getElementById('pr') = 1
    if (getElementById('pr' = 1)) {alert ('im pickle rick bitch')}
    </script>
```

So what i am trying to do is make a variable for pr and give it a value of one so it triggers the alert if pr is the image in the gallery.Hopefully i explained it good cause my english is not the best!(im also a noob)TY!

Comment: The answer you've marked as correct, is not correct. Please see my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
var foo = document.getElementById('pr');

if (foo) {alert ('im pickle rick bitch')}
```

This will fix your issue with running the code and will only show if your id exists. But I suggest you have a look at some javascript tutorials. This will help you understand Suren Srapyan's answer better.

Comment: Now your answer won't actually solve the OPs problem as the alert will be shown in every case.

Answer (score 1):

Your main issue is that if you make a variable for `pr` and then you set that variable to `1`, you'll lose the reference to `pr`.

In other words:

```
var document.getElementById("pr") = 1;
```

is not valid code because you didn't specify a variable name. But, even if you did:

```
var x = document.getElementById("pr") = 1;
```

`x` would, at first hold a reference to `pr` and then immediately lose that value and instead be set to `1`.

You also have a problem with your `if` condition because the single equal sign (`=`) is for setting a value, not comparing two values. So, your condition will always return `true`. JavaScript uses `==` and `===` for comparisons.

If you need a way to keep track of the element, you can give each element a **[data-* attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/data-*)** as shown below:

```js
var element = document.getElementById('pr');
// We can extract the data-count attribute value (a string)
// with the .dataset.count property:
if (element.dataset.count === "1") {
  alert ('im pickle rick bitch');
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <!-- The data-* attributes are designed to allow you to store meaningfull data with an element. -->
  <img id ='pr' data-count="1"
       style="width: 500px;height: 600px;" src="https://i.redd.it/2u0y0z5i12py.png">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set a value for `img`, but as I understand you need to add some extra info on the `img` tag. You can do it via [**setAttribute**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute) and [**getAttribute**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute) methods.

In your code you have some errors. Your variable declaring is wrong. You need to give to your variable a name, in my case it's `myPr` and assign to it the vlaue which return `document.getElementById` not just `getElementById`. Then use `setAttribute` method to set some HTML5 constraint attribute called `dataId`. After it you can use `getAttribute` method to get that value and use in your logic.

```js
const myPr = document.getElementById('pr');
myPr.setAttribute('dataId', 1);

if(Number.parseInt(myPr.getAttribute('dataId')) === 1) {
   alert ('im pickle rick *****');
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
<img id ='pr' style="width: 500px;height: 600px;"src="https://i.redd.it/2u0y0z5i12py.png">
</div>
```

Comment: yes but it only needs to activate if its that image if its another it doesnt need to say im picke rick

Comment: Yes, according to the attribute value which we set you can write your logic. Get that attribute an compare with which you want.

Comment: i tried and i think im confused again.to be honest i dont even know what parseint is so ill do a bit of research but thank you for your help

Comment: Your data in the attirbute is a string, I use parseInt to convert it into the number for comparing with number. If you will compare with a string, you dont need this step

Comment: but i still dont understand,what do i need to change of your code in order to make it that only 'pr' triggers it

Comment: I don't know your code. I think you need first to learn JS and then write a code on it. You need to understand the code, not to copy paste